# How to cleanly uninstall programs?

Tags: uninstall

I just uninstalled my first program in Ubuntu (gtg - getting things gnome) and noticed that it didn't clean after itself.
It left .config/gtg and .local/share/gtg

both full with configs and task info

Is that the norm in ubuntu? How to cleanly uninstall programs?

Answer (score 0):

use purge

```
sudo apt-get purge <application name>
```

purge program to remove.

Comment: OP asked about configuration left in home directory, purge removes only system level configuration, which is by design.

Comment: How does purge from the terminal differs from clicking remove in the app centre?

Comment: purge purges the customization too i.e if you installed a program made changes in settings and then remove it through app center later if you install that same software again you may find the setting you changed previously appear but if you purge it and then reinstall the program again i'll be fresh but as jnv said it removes config files only at sys level

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge APP
```

This one purges the app with its configuration files, along with extra packages that are no longer necessary. As for the files in the home folder, you will have to delete those manually. I don't think there is a way to automatically remove them.